# How to create a relation table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables, `students`, `courses`, `enroll` with relation as "students enroll in courses"

I have created `students` table with `sid` as primary key

I have created `courses` table with `cid` as primary key

Now I have to create `enroll` table which I did as follows, but it shows an error on the keyword `references`, what is the mistake ?

```
create table enroll(
    grade char(2),
    sid int not null,
    cid int not null,
    primary key(sid,cid),
    foreign key cid references courses on delete cascade,
    foreign key sid references students on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  And, is this homework?

Comment: I'm using MySQL with eclipse. Yes, this is homework!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify which fields you're referencing in the foreign table, and both sets of key field(s) must be bracketed `()` as well.

```
foreign key (cid) references courses (name_of_foreign_field_here) on delete cascade,
            ^   ^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oh, and you have to have `()` around the local key fields as well. My bad, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Another doubt, now I have created my enroll table, my student table had 200 'sid' entries, how can I copy all that to my enroll table?

Comment: there's a `insert into ... select from` syntax you can use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Also,Do you know how to insert random values to table field? like if i want to enter 100 virtual(imaginary) phone numbers of 100 students, how can i do that?

Comment: @user1291453 Please post separate questions as you have them - this is meant to be a Q&A site, not a threaded forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

simple piece of advice

for many to many relationship tables you have to make another relation table,  and take PK ids of both the tables and save in this relationship table

while for a one to many relationship table put an attribute for the PK of the one table in the attributes of the many table and always link them like that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the cid and sid in braces. This is a sample code try it out and let know your result.
Please make sure that the size and data type of the references i.e. the primary keys of course and student and that of enroll are the same.

```
CREATE TABLE `enroll` (
    `sid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `cid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`sid`, `cid`),
    INDEX `FK_enroll_course` (`cid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_enroll_course` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `course` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_enroll_student` FOREIGN KEY (`sid`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```