# how to design a expandable database?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm now working on a card game reference website. I need to have a table that I'm sure I will expand it in the future.

For example, if I have a table that is used to save the attributes of cards, and each card has the following information:

```
card_name    rarity    race    skill1
```

In the future, the game may add another skill or other information for this card like this:

```
card_name    rarity    race    skill1    skill2    others
```

In this case, I am wondering what is the best solution for me to design the database. Do I add new columns or use another table to save the new information of the cards?

Also, I'm looking for some tips that I have to watch out. BTW, I'm using mySQL

Answer (score 0):

Create a relation table. Add a primary key `id` to the cards table, what is autoincrement, and store the base data for cards. Then create a relation table, where the foreing key is the card table id. Later you can extend that table.

Here is a post about, how to create it: [How to create a relation table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145784/how-to-create-a-relation-table-in-mysql)

Here is a littlebit more detailed post about it: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/relational-databases-defining-relationships-between-database-tables/

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at a "key value pair" table, though it is considered to be a bad practice in a relational database. If the card game attributes/skills won't change that often (e.g. one or twice a year) I would got with a alter statement each time and expand the table. Otherwise a key/value table gives you the freedom to add as much attributes as you like.